# Coloring and customising SQLPlus prompt in shell

Tags: shell, colors, terminal, sqlplus

I want to change the color of sql prompt in sqlplus running in Linux.
I dont want  to modify glogin file as it may affect other scripts.Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to look at terminal color options.
For example, https://superuser.com/questions/610058/different-color-for-command-and-output

Maybe you could create an alias to sqlplus that first uses tput (or whatever)?

edit: 2 additional thoughts....

- You can use a logon.sql in your working directory that behaves just like
  the glogin.sql.
- Here's an example of
  using color *within* sqlplus:

---

```
select
    chr(27)||'[35m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(rownum+29)||'mTest' d
 ,  chr(27)||'[36m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(rownum+29)||'mTest' e
 ,  chr(27)||'[37m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(rownum+29)||'mTest' f
 ,  chr(27)||'[38m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(rownum+29)||'mTest' g
 ,  chr(27)||'[39m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(rownum+29)||'mTest' h
from dual
    connect by level<=5
```

... it'll even leave your xterm display in a lovely color state ...

Complete credit to http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2012/09/19/sqlplus-is-my-second-home-part-6-colorizing-sqlplus-and-terminal-output/

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is helpful .But I looking for something like , If a dba logins as sysdba then color of prompt should be changed automatically without changing anything big.As we are trying to implement this in prod servers.